How to get the listobject column number that matches the listcolumn name
I use the following and it returns the column of the worksheet instead of the column number of the table/list object:
InputTable.ListColumns(strDate).Range.Column

InputTable is a listobject

Currently it is returning 10 (Worksheet column number) when it should be returning 8 (ListColumns number)
Question:
how do I change my reference to return the table column instead of the worksheet column

ListColumns(strDate).Index ?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listcolumn.index

@TimWilliams DATS IT!!!!! Please make it an answer so I can accept it

ListColumns(strDate).Index is the column position within the list
See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listcolumn.index
